# Design our SharePoint lists so we do not have more than 50,000 items with unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

As mentioned in this link about SharePoint limitations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-descriptio... that we can only have up to 50,000 items with unique permissions. while the SharePoint list can have up to 30 million items. so how we need to design our SharePoint lists so they do not exceed the 50,000 unique limitation? i am talking about lists and not libraries

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, [the supported limit of unique permissions for items in a SharePoint list is 50,000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/error-share-break-inheritance). However, the recommended general limit is 5,000.Therefore, for large lists, design the list to have as few unique permissions as possible. If there is too much information, put it in multiple lists as needed.